# Elasticsearch sort on derivative aggregation to find trending topics

Tags: elasticsearch

I am collecting twitter data and want to find the account that received the highest number of new followers during a period of 48 hours.

The index is populated regularly with account data and a count of followers, together with a datestamp.

I got so far as by getting a derivative value, but I can't figure out how to sort on the derivative so as to return the accounts with the highest derivatives (accounts which won or lost the highest amount of followers during the last 48 hours).

The mapping:

```
    {
      "twfollowers" : {
        "mappings" : {
          "twfollowers" : {
            "properties" : {
              "followers" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "logDate" : {
                "type" : "date"
              },
              "screen_name" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "user_id" : {
                "type" : "long"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

And here is the query:

```
    GET /twfollowers/twfollowers/_search
    {
       "query": {
          "bool" : {             
              "must" : {
                  "range": {"logDate": {
                    "gte" : "now-2d/d",
                    "lt" :  "now/d"
                  }}
              }
          }     
       },
       "size": 0,
       "aggs": {
          "users": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "screen_name.keyword",
                "size": 10
            },
            "aggs": {
              "my_date_histo": {                  
                 "date_histogram": {
                    "field": "logDate",
                    "interval": "day"
                 },
                 "aggs": {
                    "the_sum": {
                       "max": {
                          "field": "followers"     
                       }
                    },
                    "the_diff": {
                       "derivative": {             
                          "buckets_path": "the_sum"
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
            }
          }
       }
    }
```

And finally the results:

```
    {
      "took": 12,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 129621,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "users": {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 356,
          "sum_other_doc_count": 122394,
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": "Sero83954560",
              "doc_count": 968,
              "my_date_histo": {
                "buckets": [
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-03T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1535932800000,
                    "doc_count": 268,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 870
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1536019200000,
                    "doc_count": 700,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 873
                    },
                    "the_diff": {
                      "value": 3
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "Hajk",
              "doc_count": 913,
              "my_date_histo": {
                "buckets": [
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-03T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1535932800000,
                    "doc_count": 287,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 1529
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1536019200000,
                    "doc_count": 626,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 1532
                    },
                    "the_diff": {
                      "value": 3
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "idagoraSE",
              "doc_count": 831,
              "my_date_histo": {
                "buckets": [
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-03T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1535932800000,
                    "doc_count": 173,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 1165
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1536019200000,
                    "doc_count": 658,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 1166
                    },
                    "the_diff": {
                      "value": 1
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "Dodgeman2ever",
              "doc_count": 779,
              "my_date_histo": {
                "buckets": [
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-03T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1535932800000,
                    "doc_count": 235,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 2017
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1536019200000,
                    "doc_count": 544,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 2031
                    },
                    "the_diff": {
                      "value": 14
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "KettilsMead",
              "doc_count": 743,
              "my_date_histo": {
                "buckets": [
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-03T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1535932800000,
                    "doc_count": 453,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 2860
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1536019200000,
                    "doc_count": 290,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 2862
                    },
                    "the_diff": {
                      "value": 2
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "BWhalbergarvid",
              "doc_count": 683,
              "my_date_histo": {
                "buckets": [
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-03T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1535932800000,
                    "doc_count": 87,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 200
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1536019200000,
                    "doc_count": 596,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 203
                    },
                    "the_diff": {
                      "value": 3
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "MorKarins",
              "doc_count": 601,
              "my_date_histo": {
                "buckets": [
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-03T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1535932800000,
                    "doc_count": 86,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 3874
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1536019200000,
                    "doc_count": 515,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 3875
                    },
                    "the_diff": {
                      "value": 1
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "erlhel",
              "doc_count": 593,
              "my_date_histo": {
                "buckets": [
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-03T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1535932800000,
                    "doc_count": 218,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 730
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1536019200000,
                    "doc_count": 375,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 730
                    },
                    "the_diff": {
                      "value": 0
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "SaveSweden2018",
              "doc_count": 560,
              "my_date_histo": {
                "buckets": [
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-03T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1535932800000,
                    "doc_count": 157,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 711
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1536019200000,
                    "doc_count": 403,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 732
                    },
                    "the_diff": {
                      "value": 21
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "MXCartoons",
              "doc_count": 556,
              "my_date_histo": {
                "buckets": [
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-03T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1535932800000,
                    "doc_count": 40,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 4313
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-09-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1536019200000,
                    "doc_count": 516,
                    "the_sum": {
                      "value": 4315
                    },
                    "the_diff": {
                      "value": 2
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I finally solved this by scrapping derivative altogether, and instead use extended_stats, and ordering on that value in the term aggregation.